# Searching multiple geodatabases for feature classes and merging the results

Tags: arcpy, merge, file-geodatabase

I've got some Sea Level Rise data from NOAA (https://coast.noaa.gov/slrdata/) stored in 66 different geodatabases. Each geodatabase represents a state or district and contains a set of feature classes of sea level rise at different depth (0 feet, 1 feet,...). As is shown in these pictures:

[image]

[image]

My aim is to merge all the features that have the same water depth, for example, 0 feet, to a single feature class to create a sea level rise map of the US at different water depths. So I used Arcpy to find polygon feature classes that end with "slr_0ft" through these geodatabases.  And then merge the results to one single feature class. Here's the code I used:

```
import arcpy, os
workspace = "G:\DirectStudy\SLR\gdb" #My workspace that contains 66 GDBs
search = "slr_0ft"
feature_classes = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace,
                                                  datatype="FeatureClass",
                                                  type="ANY"):
    for fname in filenames:
        # search for string in string to eliminate the need for exact filenames
        if search.upper() in fname.upper():
            feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dirpath, fname))
    for fc in feature_classes:
         print fc

arcpy.Merge_management(feature_classes, "G:\DirectStudy\SLR\Merge_0ft")  
print "Done!!"
```

The code was successful in printing paths and filenames (see below). But the output file from the merge function is an empty shapefile. I checked it with ArcMap and found it contains no polygon. Also, the script didn't give me any kind of error or warning. I guess the mistake should be in the `arcpy.Merge_management()` function. How can I fix my script?
[image]

I'm not a native speaker so I tried best to explain my question clearly.

Comment: Could you please report the results from `print(feature_classes)`?

Comment: @Aaron only the beginning part of it:[u'G:\\DirectStudy\\SLR\\gdb\\ALFL_MOB_TLH_slr_final_dist.gdb\\ALFL_MOB_TLH1_slr_0ft', u'G:\\DirectStudy\\SLR\\gdb\\ALFL_MOB_TLH_slr_final_dist.gdb\\ALFL_MOB_TLH2_slr_0ft', u'G:\\DirectStudy\\SLR\\gdb\\ALFL_MOB_TLH_slr_final_dist.gdb\\ALFL_MOB_TLH3_slr_0ft',  ...                                                                                                                          It managed to find the paths and files names I want but failed in merge all this feature classes together. It seems the code can only process merge in just 3 or 4 GDBs.

Comment: It looks like you need to define a valid output featureclass in the merge tool. It appears as if you are defining an output directory rather than an output featureclass.

Comment: try `arcpy.Merge_management(feature_classes, "G:\DirectStudy\SLR\Merge_0ft")` code inside bit to align two `for` loop and try.  Just wild guess..!

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @Aaron](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370831/searching-multiple-geodatabases-for-feature-classes-and-merging-the-results/411624#comment605795_370831):

> It looks like you need to define a valid output featureclass in the
> merge tool. It appears as if you are defining an output directory
> rather than an output featureclass.